# Where to find app location in ios simulator for xcode 4.3?

Tags: simulator, xcode4.3

I'm trying to put a custom app in the simulator's app folder for xcode4.3
anyone knows where this app folder for our own written apps went?

Comment: well, I resolved this myself. It's under xocde/contents/developer/platforms/iphonesimulator.platform/developer/applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this myself. It's under xocde/contents/developer/platforms/iphonesimulator.platform/developer/applicatio‌​ns